# scope variable - Error while assigning value to variable

Tags: angular, typescript

How to access a variable from within callback of a function. I'll show the example to be more direct in the question

```
export class FormComponent {

  public pedidoSoft:PedidoSoft = new PedidoSoft();

  getBrandCard(){

       PagSeguroDirectPayment.getBrand({

            cardBin: this.pedidoSoft.numCard,
            success: function(response) {

                    this.pedidoSoft.bandCard = response.brand.name;

            },
            error: function(response) { },
            complete: function(response) { }
       });  

   }
```

I'm getting the following error. This error is when this.pedidoSoft.bandCard receives the value of response.brand.name

[image]

Comment: plus one for using Ubuntu :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `function` in TypeScript. Replace those with `()=>{}` statements instead.

```
        success: (response) => {
                this.pedidoSoft.bandCard = response.brand.name;
        },
        error: (response) => { },
        complete: (response) => { }
```

When you use `function() {}` the `this` is not persistent where as `()=>{}` keeps the `this` reference.

Your alternative is to use `bind(this)` on the functions.

Comment: Your answer resolved my problem. I've been trying to figure this out for hours. thank you.